# DatePicker Triggers WPF

Tags: wpf, triggers, datepicker

The following is wrong, but shows what I am trying to do. I have a Label and a DatePicker. The DateTime? binding is null-able, so the DatePicker can receive a null value.

Binding of the DateTime? works fine, but I would like the foreground color of the Label to change (in Xaml) if the DatePicker has a non-null value. I believe this is done with Triggers, but this is my first time using Triggers.

```
binding to: public DateTime? NewLeadDateActiveJob


<Label  Style="{StaticResource LabelStyle}"  Grid.Row="11"  Content="New Lead:">
                <Label.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="{Binding ElementName=NewLeadDateActiveJobDatePicker, Path=HasValue}">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="HotPink"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </Label.Triggers>
            </Label>
<DatePicker x:Name="NewLeadDateActiveJobDatePicker" Grid.Row="11" Margin="3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Column="1"
                        SelectedDate="{Binding objActiveJobClass.NewLeadDateActiveJob, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnValidationError=true, ValidatesOnExceptions=true}" 
                        Style="{StaticResource DatePickerStyle}" 
                        CalendarStyle="{StaticResource styleCalendar}">
            </DatePicker>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with an IValueConverter, but I would love to hear if there is a better way.

```
public class NullableDateTimeToColorConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null || value.ToString() == string.Empty)
        {
            return "Gray";
        }

        DateTime? dateTime = value as DateTime?;
        if (dateTime == null)
        {
            return "Gray";
        }

        return "Green";
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with DataTriggers, definitely don't need a converter:

```
<Label Grid.Row="11"  Content="New Lead:">
    <Label.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Label}" BasedOn="{StaticResource LabelStyle}">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=NewLeadDateActiveJobDatePicker, Path=SelectedDate}" Value="{x:Null}">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground"  Value="Gray" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=NewLeadDateActiveJobDatePicker, Path=SelectedDate}" Value="">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground"  Value="Gray" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Label.Style>
</Label>
```